# Prometheus - Docker/JVM Monitoring

Tags: docker, jvm, prometheus

I am planning to use Prometheus for monitoring JVM within the Docker Container. We achieved this with javaagent for JMX exporter. My question is how do I dynamically discover and update my prometheus.yml for scrape targets of JVM to be monitored when I bring up/down a docker container. I am running tomcat within the docker container. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance and Appreciate your time.
Karthik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on how you do service discovery generally. For example if you're using Consul you can use Consul SD in Prometheus to find your exporter, possibly using something like Gliderlab's Registrator. http://www.slideshare.net/brianbrazil/prometheus-and-docker-docker-galway-november-2015 slides 18 and 20 should help point you in the right direction.

Other than Consul, in your situation the other main option would be to use Zookeeper Serverset or get your configuration management to write out yaml/json target files for use by Prometheus.

Comment: Hi, When I retrieve all the services from Consul, I need to filter the services based on a regex within prometheus config file but it is not accepting it. It is required to list full service name to connect to or need to leave it empty to have all services to connect to. How do I achieve this functionality within services field in _consul_sd_config?

Comment: Leave the field blank to get them all, and then use a drop or keep action in relabel_configs to filter.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at SPM Client docker container.  It has the agents for monitoring a number of different applications running in Docker - Elasticsearch, Solr, Tomcat, MySQL, and so on: https://github.com/sematext/docker-spm-client